# MySQL query to return AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

Just a practice problem, little bit confusing I'd appreciate it if somebody could clear this up..

I have a DB called Product and another one called PC. I'm trying to execute a query to "find the average hard disk size of a PC for all those manufacturers who also make printers"

Here's my code:

```
SELECT maker, AVG(hd) 
FROM pc, product
WHERE pc.model=product.model
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(type='PR')>=1
```

type is an attribute of Product which either stands for printer(PR) laptop or PC, however the HAVING statement doesn't seem to single out only the makers who produce printers, instead I get back an AVG for each maker in the Product table.

**UPDATE**

This is what the relations look like:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(model, hd, speed, ram, price)
Printer(model, color, type, price)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT maker, AVG(hd) FROM PC, Product
WHERE PC.model=Product.model
AND Product.maker IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='PR')
GROUP BY Product.maker;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abfaa/2

You simply add a condition to make sure that the maker is one of the makers that have at least one printer product.  You then group by the maker to find the individual averages.

Answer (score 1):

All those manufacturers who make printers:

```
  SELECT maker
    FROM product
   WHERE type = 'PR'
GROUP BY maker;
```

Average hard disk size of a PC for all those manufacturers who also make printers

```
  SELECT p.maker, AVG(pc.hd) avg_hd_size
    FROM
       (
  SELECT maker
    FROM product
   WHERE type = 'PR'
GROUP BY maker
       ) g
    JOIN product p on p.maker = g.maker
    JOIN pc on pc.model = p.model
GROUP BY p.maker;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

**SELECT** maker, avg(hd)

**FROM** PC **INNER JOIN** Product

**ON** PC.model=Product.model

**GROUP BY** maker

**HAVING** maker IN (**SELECT DISTINCT** maker **FROM** Product **WHERE** type='Printer')

Answer (score 0):

SELECT maker, AVG(hd) AS "average HDD capacity"
FROM Product
Inner Join PC
ON PC.model=Product.model
Where maker IN
(select maker from product
Where type = 'PC'
Intersect
select maker from product
Where type = 'Printer')
Group by maker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct maker
      ,avg(hd) as Avg_hd
  from Product
 inner join PC on (Product.model = PC.model)
 where type = 'Pc'
   and maker in (Select maker from Product where type = 'Printer')
 Group by maker
```

Comment: Usually people provide an explanation of the code posted in an answer.